# objects not deleting from database. Django, Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, sql-delete

I have the following models:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    streetaddress1 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    streetaddress2 = models.CharField(max_length=150 ,null=True, blank=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    declined = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    eventplannerstaff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    declineddate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    declineddatestring = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    declinereason = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)


class Room(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    privateroom = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    semiprivateroom = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    seatedcapacity = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    standingcapacity = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have a REST endpoint with a delete method.

I am trying to delete a room. A room is tied to a venue. I am not deleting the room directly as I want to expose the venue in this method. The permission code isn't written yet, but I will be wanting to see if the user has the permissions to mess around with the venues room.

The delete method is working but it is not actually deleting the rooms from the database. What am I doing wrong?

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        venuepk = kwargs.get('venuepk', None)
        venue = get_object_or_404(Venue, pk=venuepk)
        venuerooms = venue.room_set.all()
        roompk = kwargs.get('roompk')
        roomobject = None
        for room in venuerooms:
            if room.pk == roompk:
               roomobject = Room.objects.get(pk=roompk)
               roomobject.delete()
               roomobject.save()
               return Response({})

        return Response(status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you recreate them:

```
 roomobject.delete()
 roomobject.save()
```

First line delete the room, second line saves them again with the same ID.
If you want to delete them, only call `.delete()`

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
roomobject.save()
```

It writes back the object to the db.